# Angularjs split last hour in 10 minutes slices

Tags: angularjs, charts

Is there a way I can take the time between now and last hour and split it in 10 minutes slices in AngularJS? Something like below

```
10:00:00

09:50:00

09:40:00

09:30:00

09:20:00

09:10:00

09:00:00
```

The start time code is

```
//time now -1 hour
$scope.startTime = new Date( (new Date) * 1 - 1000 * 3600 * 1 );
```

And for end time I am using

```
//time now
$scope.endTime = new Date();
```

To make it a genuine date I am using this function

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhmm = function() {
       var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
       var mm = this.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (this.getMonth() + 1) : (this.getMonth() + 1); // getMonth() is zero-based
       var dd  = this.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + this.getDate() : this.getDate();
       var hh = this.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + this.getHours() : this.getHours();
       var min = this.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + this.getMinutes() : this.getMinutes();
       var sec = this.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + this.getSeconds() : this.getSeconds();
       return "".concat(yyyy + '-').concat(mm + '-').concat(dd + ' ').concat(hh + ':').concat(min + ':').concat(sec);
    };
```

What I need the 10 minutes slices is for a Line Chart labels.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code and  as below,

js code as below

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.timeList = [];
   $scope.seconds = 0;
   var time = formatAMPM(new Date( (new Date) * 1 + 1000 * 0 * 1 ));
   $scope.timeList.push(time);
   for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
   {
      $scope.seconds = $scope.seconds + 600;
      var time = formatAMPM(new Date( (new Date) * 1 + 1000 * $scope.seconds * 1 ));
      $scope.timeList.push(time);

   }

   function formatAMPM(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
    }
});
```

Html Code as below,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="time in timeList">
    {{time}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this JSFiddle Link: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oy7q4cf4/)

OutPut is as below:

3:44 pm
3:54 pm
4:04 pm
4:14 pm
4:24 pm
4:34 pm
4:44 pm

Hope this helps you

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var endTime = new Date();
var startTime = new Date( endTime.getTime() - 1000 * 3600 );
var time = startTime;
while (time < endTime) {
    time = new Date(time.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 10);
    // do something with the generated time
}
```

This doesn't use anything you didn't already use, I'm confused as to what you got stuck on.